# R sum column in second table based on if conditions

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr, rmysql

I am trying to sum the column in another table and put it in my current table based on a number of conditions.

```
table1 <- tribble(~company_id,~date,
                  1,"2018-01-02",
                  1,"2018-01-03",
                  2,"2018-01-02",
                  2,"2018-01-03")

table2 <- tribble(~other_id, company_id,~date_created,~max_rank,rank,date_closed,
                  1,1,"2018-01-02",20,2,NA,
                  1,1,"2018-01-03",22,1,NA,
                  2,2,"2018-01-02",20,5,NA,
                  2,2,"2018-01-03",22,4,NA)
```

I want to create a new column in table 1 that will imput the following formula:

```
= sum( (max_rank-rank)/(max_rank-1))
```

but only when:

```
(date<=date_created, date>(date_created+20), date<date_closed, max_rank-1!=0, rank!=0)
```

**Edit**

The output I hope to achieve should look like this:

```
 Table 1 
    | company id | date        | cc score |
    ---------------------------------------
    | 1          |  2018-01-02 |  0.9473  |
    | 1          |  2018-01-03 |  1.9473  |
    | 2          |  2018-01-02 |  0.7895  |
    | 2          |  2018-01-03 |  1.6466  |
```

The first can be calculated as (20-2)/(20-1) = 0.9473
The second is calculated as (20-2)/(20-1) + (22-1)/(22-1) = 1.9473

Comment: Can you please show you expected output?

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful if you posted your data in a more reproducible format instead of as text. Use `dput(head(your_data))` and post the result.

Comment: Looks like your dataset is `data.frame` and not `data.table`. try `setDT(table1)` and then apply yiour code

Comment: @akrun I tried that but it didnt work

Comment: Ok, my comment was based on the error you showed.  Can you please `dput` the two examples and copy/paste the output in your post to get the structure of data correct

Comment: :-) in case you want to make it easy for others to work on your dat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
table1[, cc_score := table2[table1, 
     on = .(company_id = company_id, date_created<=date, date_created_pls_20>date), 
     sum(ifelse(!is.na(rank) & (is.na(date_closed) | date_closed>date),
     ((max_rank-rank)/(max_rank-1)), 0)),
     by = .EACHI][["V1"]]]
```

Where `date_created_pls_20` is a column that takes the `date_created` column and simply adds 20

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dplyr** package.
Please try the code below:

```
> library(dplyr)
> cbind(table1,table2)%>%inner_join(table1)%>%inner_join(table2)%>%filter(date<=date_created|date>(date_created+20)&max_rank-1!=0&rank!=0)%>%mutate(cc_data=(max_rank-rank)/(max_rank-1))%>%group_by(company_id)%>%mutate(cc_data=cumsum(cc_data))%>%select(company_id,date,cc_data)
```

- **Use of cbind()** : We need both date_created and date column.
- **Two times inner_join()**: To make sure there is no extra data.

> Please suggest a better solution than this.

Comment: these are very big tables and the dplyr package performance is insufficient as it tries to merge them to create a table that is simply too big